# Export data from always open, live-updating Excel document every 10 seconds

Tags: c#, sql, excel

Is it possible to export data from an Excel document that is always open and constantly updating its values? This can be through any means(SQL, python, excel macro, text document). The Excel document was setup by a third party vendor that pumps their live data into the Excel document.

The main problem I'm running into is the fact that the document is never being saved. Meaning, the data is being refreshed on Excel but never actually being "saved" on the local drive. Therefore the only data I actually have access to is the last time the "save" button was pressed on the Excel document. Closing the document is not really an option because this will prevent it from updating altogether. Manually pressing the save button is not feasible either as the data is live.

What I have tried so far;

1. Using an SQL server agent job. The server agent job however is not able to access a file that is open.
2. Programmatically opening the file and accessing its contents through a C# console application. This is where the 'last saved' problem described above is prevalent.
3. Setting Excel to save the document every 10 seconds through its autosave settings (This only modifies the save timer on the "recovery" information not the actual information being stored on the drive).

Comment: Why does such an Excel file exist in the first place? Are you trying to clone what the user does? Or is this an attempt to use Excel as something it's definitely not - a web service? Neither Google Sheet nor Excel Online run an Excel instance in the background. `a third party vendor that pumps their live data into the Excel document.` that's a very unfortunate hack. And reason to find a better vendor

Comment: Obviously a bad design as Excel should never be used as a database, it's best use is as a database client only.  Here's a thought, you already will have everything you need in memory.  Create a method which will create a new document, but copy the in-memory data piece by piece.  That method will then save the document.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to deal with the hack is more hacks. One possibility would be to use a VBA macro to save the data periodically, or retrieve all cell values and export them *somewhere*. This would avoid the synchronization issues if multiple applications tried to read from the same Excel instance at the same time it was updated. Calling Excel is only possible through COM/Excel Interop. You'd have to access the shared instance instead of creating a new Excel instance and try to read the sheet's data. The API is the same one used for VBA macros. You *will* run into sync issues though

Comment: You could develop an Excel VSTO addin in one of the supported .NET languages, which can then run every x seconds to do the data sync.

Answer (score 0):

python with xlwings?

use xlwings to read your live data into a dataframe and then python-export that dataframe out into whatever---